# Jailbreak: Need Top Option + Restore + Choose ipsw Anymore?

Tags: jailbreak

Before a device was to be jailbreaked, all the tutorials recommended connecting said device to iTunes and then clicking <kbd>option</kbd> + `Restore > Choose ipsw`.

Recent tutorials don't include these steps any more. Rather they just mention restoring through iTunes and not over wifi.

Is the <kbd>option</kbd> + `Restore > Choose ipsw` Necessary Still For Jailbreaking?

Comment: It's not necessary if you're jailbreaking on the latest iOS version. However for older versions, apple has stopped signing them, which makes it harder to jailbreak on an older iOS version.

Answer (score 1):

The basic restore through `iTunes` will download the latest software image and restore it. This is equivalent to downloading the latest ipsw and using the <kbd>Option</kbd> + `Restore` method.

The <kbd>Option</kbd> + `restore` method has typically been useful for situations where you need to restore to an older or modified ipsw file, which was more useful in the earlier days of jailbreaking.